# How to find Integral of Branch ROOT

Tags: root-framework

I have a TTree with branches. I am able to plot the branch using

```
treename -> Draw("branchname")
```

However, I also want to know the integral of this plot.

I am trying something like

```
treename->GetIntegral("branchname")
```

but I am getting an error that says "GetIntegral" is not a member of TBranch

Comment: You should probably find a different tag. "Root" is the tag used for questions about the administrative password under unix/linux (root).

Answer (score 1):

put the branch data ( >>)  into a temp storage histogram "STOR"

```
treename -> Draw("branchname>>STOR")
```

then use this STOR to find the integral

```
STOR -> Integral()
```

which gives you a number output!